# Out of flow div, but not absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning, qtip2

I have a big `div` with a big background-image. Now I want to create some `div`'s and to put them over some elements in the background image, then use qTip2 to give some explanations. In the middle I want to put a form.

```
<div id="bigdiv" style="background-image:url('back.jpg')">
    <div id="qtipbox1"></div>
    <div id="qtipbox2"></div>
    <div id="form"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is: if I use `position relative` for the qTip boxes the form goes down. If I use `absolute` `position`, results are different as I resize window.

What do I have to do?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you posted some of your code.

Comment: try to use absolute positioning with `%` based values instead of `px`, i.e. `{ position: absolute; top: 15%; left: 20%; }`

Comment: OOps, I'm sorry! There's the code now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'd help if you'd share the relevant code or (even better) put up a sample on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Anyhow, you use `position: relative` on the container `div` with the big background image and then use `position: absolute` on the elements inside. That way, they should be absolutely positioned *relatively to the container*.